# How to get WKT from SHAPE column in the ArcSDE geodatabase?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, sql-server, well-known-text

I have an ArcSDE geodatabase running on top of SQL Server 2008. A table for a feature layer was added from ArcCatalog. The SHAPE column is a type of int which was automatically converted from ArcCatalog.

**My question is:**

In SQL Server Management Studio, what is the best SQL syntax to output WKT for each of the records in the table?

p.s. `[SHAPE].STAsText()` doesn't work in

```
SELECT [OBJECTID] ,[SHAPE], [SHAPE].STAsText() FROM [sde].[sdl_admin].[POINT_LOCATION]

Cannot find either column "SHAPE" or the user-defined function or aggregate 
SHAPE.STAsText", or the name is ambiguous.
```

Comment: I'm not on a workstation with ArcCatalog, but if your datatype on `SHAPE` is an int then you using SDEBINDARY for your geometry storage.   If you re-import your featureclass, there will be an option to change the `KEYWORD` to ST_GEOMETRY.  You might have to expand a section to see the drop-down list.  I think if you copy/paste, the keyword is in a grid and the cell is a drop-down list.  Then your `SHAPE` will be ST_GEOMETRY and your geometry methods will work (including your `STAsText()`).